# Post multiple values via javascript ajax to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am currently working on a php project. I need to post two values, a username and password value to a php script to check that a user account exists.

I have it working fine posting the username only but don't know how to post multiple values to it.

Below is the code that I currently have

```
function checkAccount()
        {
            var username = $(\'#txtUsername\').val();
            var password = $(\'#txtPassword\').val();

            $.post("phpHandler/login.php"), {username: username},
                function(result)
                {
                    if (result == "unknownUser")
                    {
                        $(\'#msg\').html("Unknown username and password").addClass(\'formError\');
                        $(\'#msg\').fadeIn("slow");
                    }
                }
        }
```

For the line

> $.post("phpHandler/login.php"), {username: username},

I tried to do

> $.post("phpHandler/login.php"), {username: username, password:
>   password},
>   but this doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes in your $() calls? That turns the quotes into "part-of-the-string" so jquery is looking for some element literally named `'#txtPassword'`, and not an element with id `#txtPassword`.

Comment: its because its within a php script and the html/javascript is surrounded with ' that's why its escaped so its not actually looking for '#txtPassword'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax errors all over the place between your escaped quotes and the early closing parens on your `.post` call.  This code will work assuming no other issues exist in your supporting code:

```
function checkAccount()
{
    $.post(
        'phpHandler/login.php',
        {
            username: $( '#txtUsername' ).val(),
            password: $( '#txtPassword' ).val()
        },
        function( result )
        {
            if( result === 'unknownUser' )
            {
                $( '#msg' )
                    .html( 'Unknown username and password' )
                    .addClass( 'formError' )
                    .fadeIn("slow");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
$.post("phpHandler/login.php", {username: username, password: password}, function(){
  // success code goes here
});
```

You are closing the parenthesis of post function before passing the parameters.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, i'm not sure that it`s calling the underneath function where it checks the result of the post statement

Comment: @Boardy - When using the `.ajax` shortcuts (such as `.post`), if anything goes wrong it fails silently. Your success function never runs and no error occurs. If this is a possibility, you should switch to `.ajax` while developing and provide an error method which lets you know something went wrong.